# Why shadowRoot cannot be removed?

Tags: javascript, html

You can use `attachShadow` to create a shadowDOM, but there is no api like `removeShadow` or any other offcial way to remove it, that's why?
Why this design?

Comment: the real question is, why do you need to remove it

Comment: Closing it makes it inaccessible and `null` which is about as close to being removed as you could get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a shadow root from an HTML element adorned with a Shadow DOM from a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090059/how-to-remove-a-shadow-root-from-an-html-element-adorned-with-a-shadow-dom-from)

Comment: @SuperStormer Actually, I'm posting this after I read the question you mentioned. I mean, there's always a way to remove the shadowRoot, but ECMA seems to prefer people not do this, intentionally. This is what I don't understand.